# Overriding Bootstrap Container Full Width Background Color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have my container divs background color extend to the full width of the browser. Right now I am unable to bypass the container styling set up by default in bootstrap, despite adding my own class to the container. The only styling that works is the `background-color`. I have also tried the following CSS, but it didn't make any change.

```
margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    background-color: #FDDC00;
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container selection-section">
        <div class="row pattern-choice">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2><i>Choose a pattern</i></h2>
                <ul>
                    <li class="button-border">
                        <h3 class="button-choice" ><a href="/solid/color" class="button-link" id="solid-choice">SOLID</a></h3>
                    </li>
                    <li class="button-border">
                        <h3 class="button-choice" id="stripe-choice"><a href="/stripe/color" class="button-link" id="stripe-choice">STRIPE</a></h3>
                    </li>
                    <li class="button-border">
                        <h3 class="button-choice" id="plaid-choice"><a href="/plaid/color" class="button-link" id="plaid-choice">PLAID</a></h3>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.selection-section {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    background-color: #FDDC00;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `container-fluid` instead of `container` if you want the container to extend to the full-width of your webpage.

Answer (score 2):

If it's only the color that's a concern surrounding the `container` with another div might work for you.

```css
.selection-section {
  background: #FDDC00;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="selection-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row pattern-choice">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2><i>Choose a pattern</i></h2>

        <ul>
          <li class="button-border">
            <h3 class="button-choice"><a href="/solid/color" class="button-link" id="solid-choice">SOLID</a></h3>

          </li>
          <li class="button-border">
            <h3 class="button-choice" id="stripe-choice"><a href="/stripe/color" class="button-link" id="stripe-choice">STRIPE</a></h3>

          </li>
          <li class="button-border">
            <h3 class="button-choice" id="plaid-choice"><a href="/plaid/color" class="button-link" id="plaid-choice">PLAID</a></h3>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">Outside Div</div>
</div>
```